# Why isn't the canvas rectangle expanding?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm making an HTML5 Canvas game, and I have a rectangle that should expand when I hover over it, but it doesn't seem to do so. Here's the code where it's expanding:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        object = objects[i]
        object.update()
    }

    if (mouse.x >= 1280 && mouse.x <= 1210) {
        if (mouse.y >= 270 && mouse.y <= 200) {
            calendarHover = true
        } else {
            calendarHover = false
        }
    } else if (calendar.width != 70 || calendar.height != 70) {
        calendar.width--
        calendar.height--
    }

    if (calendarHover == true) {
        calendar.width++
        calendar.height++
    }
}
```

Here's my whole code on codepen, if it helps: [code](https://codepen.io/Madscientist2854/pen/erxoYm)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so if you were having the same problem this will help you out. It's a simple logical error, you just have to switch the values for greater than and less than in the conditionals. Make it:

```
if (mouse.x >= 1210 && mouse.x <= 1280)
```

And:

```
if (mouse.y >= 200 && mouse.y <= 270)
```